# Using routes with requirejs on the server side

Tags: node.js, requirejs

I'm tinkering with server side requirejs and I have a problem with routes. My routes/index.js file has:

```
/*
 * GET home page.
 */

  exports.index = function(req, res){
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
  };
});
```

and in my server.js I have:

```
 define(['express', 'module', 'path', './routes'],
  function (express, module, path, routes) {
    var app = express();

    app.configure(function() {

      // all environments
      var filename = module.uri;

      app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

      app.use(express.static(path.dirname(filename) + '/views'));
      app.set('view engine', 'jade');
      app.use(express.favicon());
      app.use(express.logger('dev'));
      app.use(express.bodyParser());
      app.use(express.methodOverride());
      app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
      app.use(express.session());
      app.use(app.router);
      app.use(express.static(path.dirname(filename) + '/public'));

    });



    // development only
    if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
      app.use(express.errorHandler());
    }

    app.get('/', routes.index);

    return app;
 });
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
500 Error: Failed to lookup view "index"
at Function.app.render (/Users/johnwesonga/backbonejs/src/helloworld/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:489:17)
at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/johnwesonga/backbonejs/src/helloworld/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:755:7)
at exports.index (/Users/johnwesonga/backbonejs/src/helloworld/routes/index.js:7:9)
at callbacks (/Users/johnwesonga/backbonejs/src/helloworld/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
at param (/Users/johnwesonga/backbonejs/src/helloworld/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
at pass (/Users/johnwesonga/backbonejs/src/helloworld/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:142:5)
at Router._dispatch (/Users/johnwesonga/backbonejs/src/helloworld/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:170:5)
at Object.router (/Users/johnwesonga/backbonejs/src/helloworld/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
at next (/Users/johnwesonga/backbonejs/src/helloworld/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
at next (/Users/johnwesonga/backbonejs/src/helloworld/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:313:9)
```

Any clue where i'm going wrong?

Comment: Try to `console.log(module.uri);` inside `app.configure`. What is the output?

Comment: That outputs:
/Users/johnwesonga/backbonejs/src/helloworld/app.js

Comment: So check whether you have file: `/Users/johnwesonga/backbonejs/src/helloworld/views/index.jade`

Comment: All there, this worked before I started using requirejs on the server side

Answer (score 0):

It could be simply that something has been cached or needs to be restarted.

Unfortunately I don't have a definitive answer, but I was having a similar problem: everything seemed to be set up correctly however I was getting an error saying that it couldn't find the view. I gave up, switched off the computer then came back to it the next morning.....and it worked.

I hope this provides a clue for anyone looking at this post, (as I did), in the future

Comment: Just as a follow up, it is definitely the case that node needs to be restarted when making changes to .js files. I even read that info already but completely forgot to do it, so drove myself crazy trying to find a complicated answer to a simple problem